# cordova events not working, what wrong am i doing

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

My code below, its not working on my android device, I wish to achieve this -

1. when my app is about to minimize, it should say `alert("bye");`
2. when i again open my app (provided its running in background) , `alert("resume");`
3. when opened for the first time, `alert("device ready");`

I thought i have done everything right, but not sure where i am wrong. Please help

```js
// example.js file
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("device ready");
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    // Add similar listeners for other events
}



function onPause() {
    // Handle the pause event
    alert("pause");
}

function onResume() {
    // Handle the resume event
    alert("resume");
}

function onMenuKeyDown() {
    // Handle the menubutton event
    alert("menu key down");
}


function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the onBackKeyDown event
    alert("back key down");
}

// Add similar event handlers for other events
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try 'document.addEventListener("pause", this.onPause, false);'

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: How do we see console on a mobile ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the console for any errors.

Also check you have the correct path for your JavaScript files. For instance make sure index.js is in the same folder as index.html and not in a separate js folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use in javascript:

```
  window.onload = function() { 
 onLoad();
 }
```

Comment: I am using like this -  `<body>
        <script>
         window.onload = function() { 
 onLoad();
 }
 </script>
    </body>`   // but still its not triggering